# Why do images reload on refresh on one server, but appear instantly on another?

Tags: html, css, image, page-refresh

These two websites are exactly the same:

http://www.inandoutofwonderland.com

http://dev.zelencomm.com/inandoutofwonderland/

However, when I press F5 to refresh (or Command-R on Mac) the former website renders immediately and without any visible image loading, the page image does not even flicker or move in any way.

When I do this on the latter copy of the site, it goes to black, and all images disappear and visibly all reload from top to bottom.

The two websites are exactly the same in both files and database. I've tested this is Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Explorer both on Windows and OSX, and I have the same behavior everywhere. The two sites are on different servers, so I can only conclude this is some server setting I am unable to track down. The servers seem to have the same speed, it's just one makes the site reload its images on refresh while the other does not.

I have tried to add the "ExpiresByType" commands into the htaccess file on the 'slow' site but it does not seem to have any effect.

I would really like to figure out what the difference is so that I can make the latter website's server behave like the former and load its images up immediately rather than have the whole top-down rendering thing.

Thanks for any insight into this.

Comment: By "seem to have the same speed," have you actually compared load times on all of the assets it's trying to load, including the HTML page itself? Also, check the HTTP headers it's sending back with the HTML page and all assets and compare. That may shed some light on some differences?

Comment: no diff accept speed.

Comment: Chris I will do that thank you, I'm not very familiar with checking HTTP headers on individual assets but I will figure it out.

Comment: I've used Firebug to look at the header of each asset and in the 'fast' version of the site, the server is returning a 304 NOT MODIFIED error for every asset on refresh. So there is literally zero load time for every single asset on the site aside from the base html file which is 14k. Meanwhile the 'slow' site is returning 200 OK and sending each asset all over again for every refresh. My objective now is to figure out how to get the 'slow' one to mimic the 304 response of the 'fast' one.